# How can I deterministically generate a seemingly random number given a seed and certain arguments?

Tags: random, noise

I wrote a Perlin noise generator, but it depends on something pretty inconvenient: I have to pregenerate a grid of random vectors.

Ideally, I'd like have some function `double f(int x, int y, int z, int seed)` (or similar) that will always return an identical value given identical arguments, but whose results appear random enough for the noise generation over small ranges of x, y, and z. Then, in my noise generation algorithm, instead of indexing into the precomputed grid, it can generate a "random" vector on the fly. This way I could sample the noise function at coordinates bounded only by the limits of an integer, rather than bounded by the limits of memory.

Is such a thing possible? Obviously the randomness wouldn't be nearly as high-quality as precomputing the vectors, but I only really need something that appears random enough visually. Are there any existing methods of doing this?

Comment: You didn't specify a language, so it's hard to say exactly. When I wrote a Game of Life simulator in c++ and wanted to deterministically generate a random population, I just passed in a seed to `srand` before using `rand` to generate the numbers. It gave me a "predictably random"  population.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Well the language doesn't really matter. I'm using C++, but I'm mostly interested in the algorithm itself. But yes, I know how to generate predictably random numbers, that isn't the issue. That's what I'm currently doing: generating all the numbers given a certain seed value. What I basically want to do is this: given a seed value and some n, I want to get the nth output of the pseudorandom number generator. Except it's not practical to call `rand()` n times every time I need the number.

Comment: @Carcigenicate The problem is finding an algorithm that gives me an acceptable appearance of randomness while being able to give the exact same output given the exact same inputs. The criteria for "acceptable appearance of randomness" for this case is, for any x, y, and z, and some seed, the output of f(x+i, y+j, z+k, seed) over some small range of i, j, k (say, -5 to 5 or something similar) don't appear to be related to the output of f(x, y, z, seed). Of course, they will be, but it just has to visually appear not to be.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question. And I'm not sure how to do that, sorry. I'm assuming you've already looked over the documentation to see if they provide any easy means to do that?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yeah, C++'s library only provides classes that are good for generating sequences of random numbers (as well as classes to form those generator outputs into distributions). There isn't anything built in to do what I'm looking for, though I'd probably build my solution using those built-ins somehow

Comment: Damn, sorry, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a hash function. There are many very good ones: for your usage, where security is less of a concern than speed, I would use something like MD5 or SHA1.

Comment: Oh, I can't believe I didn't make the connection there. I've even used hash functions before... nevertheless, thanks.